# Could not access Application Database in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I can connect to my Application database in SSMS using localhost,14344 and sa password P@ssw0rd123 if I run this command:

```
docker run --rm -p 14344:1433 --name=accsol-sqlserver solomiosisante/accsol-sqlserver:0.1.0
```

Now, I've enabled Kubernetes in Docker Desktop v4.26.1 and I can pull the sql server image from the dockerhub repo and connect to the sqlserver and system databases like sys.objects, master, etc... using SSMS but it did not show my Application Database. Here are my yaml files and commands:

**accsol-sqlserver-deployment.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: accsol-sqlserver-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: accsol-sqlserver
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: accsol-sqlserver
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: accsol-sqlserver
          image: solomiosisante/accsol-sqlserver:0.1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1433
          env:
          - name: MSSQL_PID
            value: "Express"
          - name: ACCEPT_EULA
            value: "Y"
          - name: MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: accsol-sqlserver
                key: MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/data
            name: accsol-sqlserverdb
      volumes:
      - name: accsol-sqlserverdb
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: accsol-sqlserver-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: accsol-sqlserver-clusterip-srv
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: accsol-sqlserver
  ports:
  - name: accsol-sqlserver
    protocol: TCP
    port: 14344
    targetPort: 1433
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: accsol-sqlserver-loadbalancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: accsol-sqlserver
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 14344
    targetPort: 1433
```

**accsol-sqlserver-persist-volume.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: accsol-sqlserver-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 200Mi
  local:
    path: /mnt/data
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
              operator: In
              values:
                - docker-desktop
```

**accsol-sqlserver-persist-claim.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: accsol-sqlserver-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 200Mi
```

and this is the powershel .ps1 script file I run to create the cluster, deployment, services and load the sql server container to kubernetes.

**k8sqlsetup.ps1**

```
cls

# Step 1 - Setup accsol-sqlserver cluster first =================================================>

# make sure that you are in the correct directory
cd C:\repo\AccSol\Docker    

kubectl delete deployment accsol-sqlserver-deployment
kubectl delete service accsol-sqlserver-clusterip-srv
kubectl delete service accsol-sqlserver-loadbalancer
kubectl delete secret accsol-sqlserver
kubectl delete pv accsol-sqlserver-claim


kubectl get deployments
kubectl get services
kubectl get secrets

# Create a secret to store the SA password for SQL Server
kubectl create secret generic accsol-sqlserver --from-literal=MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=P@ssw0rd123 

kubectl apply -f accsol-sqlserver-persist-volume.yaml
kubectl apply -f accsol-sqlserver-persist-claim.yaml
kubectl apply -f accsol-sqlserver-deployment.yaml

kubectl get secrets
kubectl get deployments
kubectl get services
kubectl get nodes
```

I received no error messages, I can connect to the sql server and run query the master database and sys.objects database but it did not show my Application database which I can access by running docker run (see first code example above).

Can someone explain this to me please?

Thanks in advance.